# HTML5 view inside Java desktop GUI, JavaScript communication

Tags: java, javascript, html, swing, user-interface

In this Java desktop GUI, the web services communication layer is in Java, the UI is based on a very powerful HTML library providing charting and interactivity.

How do I embed an HTML5 view inside a Java GUI and how to I handle JavaScript communication with it?

An example of how to trigger a JavaScript function, read a DOM property, etc. would help, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- this isn't possible (without using 3rd party libraries) with plain Swing and Java, because Java6 support Html <= 3.2
- this could be simple by using [JavaFX version2 and higher](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)
- even JavaFx tutorial to describe about Integrating [JavaFX into Swing Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm) I'd suggest to create plain JavaFX GUI without usage of Swings API